# Is this construction correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-construction

Let's say I am talking to my friend, he asks me

> Do you have any idea where **X** (another friend) is?

I reply

> He has **gone to get** some **Y**.(assuming I don't know where he is going to buy it from.)

I often hear **gone to the supermarket to get something**  or **gone down/up to get something**, but not sure if saying just **gone to get something** is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly fine!  Even if you do know where he's going to buy it from, you don't need to say so if it isn't relevant.  If all that matters is that he's getting [Y], this is fine.

I would imagine the full form of the sentence to be something like

> He has gone (in order) to get some [Y].

In short, yes, you may say this!